# tkinter - Why is there such a thing like bbox?

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

Now that I'm working more with tkinter Canvas I was wondering about the use of bbox.

For me I'm using bbox to get the coords of an element but the Canvas already have a method to return the coords of an item. So why did they invent something like bbox?

Comparing the official tcl description [here](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M37):

**bbox**

> pathName bbox tagOrId ?tagOrId tagOrId ...?
>
> Returns a list with four elements giving an approximate bounding box
> for all the items named by the tagOrId arguments. The list has the
> form ``x1 y1 x2 y2'' such that the drawn areas of all the named
> elements are within the region bounded by x1 on the left, x2 on the
> right, y1 on the top, and y2 on the bottom. The return value may
> overestimate the actual bounding box by a few pixels. If no items
> match any of the tagOrId arguments or if the matching items have empty
> bounding boxes (i.e. they have nothing to display) then an empty
> string is returned.

**coords**

> pathName coords tagOrId ?coordList?
>
> Query or modify the coordinates that define an item. If no coordinates
> are specified, this command returns a list whose elements are the
> coordinates of the item named by tagOrId. If coordinates are
> specified, then they replace the current coordinates for the named
> item. If tagOrId refers to multiple items, then the first one in the
> display list is used.

I see the difference between these, but can't imaging in which case I would need a bbox instead of the coords?
Can someone teach me a better understanding of this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The difference is that with `bbox()` you can get the bounding box of a group of items (using a tag or 'all') while `coords()` returns the coordinates of the first item with given tag. Here is an example

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

i1 = canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 30, 50, tags='rect')
i2 = canvas.create_rectangle(60, 80, 70, 120, fill='red', tags='rect')

canvas.update_idletasks()
print('bbox', canvas.bbox('rect'))
print('coords', canvas.coords('rect'))
```

which gives

```
bbox (9, 9, 71, 121) 
coords [10.0, 10.0, 30.0, 50.0]
```

One of the typical use of `bbox()` is when you want to scroll a group of widgets using a canvas: The scrollregion of the canvas needs to be set to include all the canvas content so `canvas.bbox('all')` is quite useful. See for instance [Adding a scrollbar to a group of widgets in Tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085696/adding-a-scrollbar-to-a-group-of-widgets-in-tkinter/3092341#3092341) (in the `onFrameConfigure()` function).

Answer (score 4):

### **Understanding bbox**

Lets take this bit of Code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

def do_bbx(event):
    item_id = event.widget.find_withtag('current')[0]
    crds = event.widget.coords(item_id)
    print(f'{item_id} was clicked')
    print(f'bbox returns, {bbx}')
    print(f'coords returns, {crds}')

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root,width=250,height=250)
f = c.create_rectangle(10,20, 50, 50,
                       fill = "BLUE")
sec = c.create_rectangle(30,30, 80, 80,
                         fill = "GREEN")
bbx = c.bbox(f, sec)
c.tag_bind('all', "<Button-1>", do_bbx)

c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

and run this which return into this:

[image]

If you click on the blue rectangle the following will be printed out:

```
1 was clicked
bbox returns, (9, 19, 81, 81)
coords returns, [10.0, 20.0, 50.0, 50.0]
```

While clicking on the green will print:

```
2 was clicked
bbox returns, (9, 19, 81, 81)
coords returns, [30.0, 30.0, 80.0, 80.0]
```

So bbox does just quiet else then compareing the values of the coordinates and returns us a list. Like:

```
import tkinter as tk

def rectangel_us(canvas, *items):
    coords = {"x1":[],"y1":[],"x2":[],"y2":[]}
    for i in items:
        coords['x1'].append(canvas.coords(i)[0])
        coords['y1'].append(canvas.coords(i)[1])
        coords['x2'].append(canvas.coords(i)[2])
        coords['y2'].append(canvas.coords(i)[3])
    x1 = min(coords['x1'])-1
    y1 = min(coords['y1'])-1
    x2 = max(coords['x2'])+1
    y2 = max(coords['y2'])+1
    return[x1,y1,x2,y2]

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root,width=250,height=250)
f = c.create_rectangle(10,20, 50, 50,
                       fill = "BLUE")
sec = c.create_rectangle(30,30, 80, 80,
                         fill = "GREEN")

bbx = rectangel_us(c, f, sec)
print(bbx)


c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

the printed out bbx will be:

```
[9.0, 19.0, 81.0, 81.0]
```

as we know from above.

This can be visible by this code here:

```
import tkinter as tk

def rectangel_us(canvas, *items):
    coords = {"x1":[],"y1":[],"x2":[],"y2":[]}
    for i in items:
        coords['x1'].append(canvas.coords(i)[0])
        coords['y1'].append(canvas.coords(i)[1])
        coords['x2'].append(canvas.coords(i)[2])
        coords['y2'].append(canvas.coords(i)[3])
    x1 = min(coords['x1'])-1
    y1 = min(coords['y1'])-1
    x2 = max(coords['x2'])+1
    y2 = max(coords['y2'])+1
    canvas.create_rectangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,
                            outline='red')

root = tk.Tk()
c = tk.Canvas(root,width=250,height=250)
f = c.create_rectangle(10,20, 50, 50,
                       fill = "BLUE")
sec = c.create_rectangle(30,30, 80, 80,
                         fill = "GREEN")

bbx = rectangel_us(c, f, sec)


c.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Which result in this:

[image]