# draw a line between 2 checkbuttons chosen with mouse click in python

Tags: python, tkinter, mouseevent, line, tkinter.checkbutton

I have a code to paste checkbuttons in a canvas. They also change colors if clicked. If I click another checkbutton that is set up from the beginning, I want to be able to draw a line between 2 checkbuttons I select with the mouse click. Also I need the line to change the color when I click the first checkbutton. Any suggestion how to do it? [image: line should be straight]

```
    from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

buttons = []

class CMD: #Auxilliary function for callbacks using parameters. Syntax: CMD(function, argument1, argument2, ...)
    def __init__(s1, func, *args):
        s1.func = func
        s1.args = args
    def __call__(s1, *args):
        args = s1.args+args
        s1.func(*args)

 def color_checkbutton(pos=0):  # define the colors of the checkbutton
    if buttons[pos][0].get() == 1:
        buttons[pos][2].configure(bg='red')
    else:
        buttons[pos][2].configure(bg='green')

def place_checkbutton_in_canvas(e):  # order to insert the checkbutton
    if len(str(e.widget))<3: ## Don't place a new one if a checkbox was clicked
        b = IntVar()
        pos = len(buttons)
        xx_and = e.x
        yy_and = e.y
        buttons.append([b,pos, Checkbutton(root, variable=b, textvariable=b, command=CMD(color_checkbutton,pos))])
        buttons[-1][2].place(x=xx_and, y=yy_and)
        color_checkbutton(pos)

root.bind('<Button-1>', place_checkbutton_in_canvas)

line = IntVar()
draw_line_check = Checkbutton(root, variable=line)
draw_line_check.place(x=30,y=100)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a lot more code and you are not even close in my opinion.

Most importantly you dont have the checkbuttons **IN** your *canvas*, you have your Checkbuttons **above** the Canvas, if you dont use somewhere `create_window` in put them in(even though in your code isnt a canvas yet). But you will like to have them in the Canvas to use the [bbox method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62712481/tkinter-why-is-there-such-a-thing-like-bbox/62716053#62716053) of the canvas later.

The next thing is how you try to save your data, with more checkbuttons it get more complex. May think about a [defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5900634/13629335), or even better define a `class(object)` where you can target them easier and define class functions for the behavior.

```
draw_line_check = Checkbutton(root, variable=line)
```

The above line will need a command where you will bind your `Button-1` to another behavior if clicked and vice versa.

So I would do it like this:

1. define a class that will place a Checkbutton on your Canvas and behave what ever you like.
2. keep track of your instances somewhere in the global namespace with a defaultdict
3. define a function that creates instances of your class.
4. write a function that rebinds your `Button-1`