# tkinter canvas.coords() and canvas.moveto() having different coordinates

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried the following script, in a `canvas` that fills the window:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from time import *

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

def fill(event):
    canvas.config(width = root.winfo_width(), height = root.winfo_height())
root.bind("<Configure>", fill)

img = Image.open("CO2.png")
imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
item = canvas.create_image(15, 15, image = imgtk)
while True:
    canvas.moveto(item, canvas.coords(item)[0], canvas.coords(item)[1])
    root.update()
    sleep(0.5)
```

This should do nothing, because it's moving an item to where it already is. But in practice, this moves the image towards the positive x and y direction, which means the coordinates from `canvas.coords()` is slightly off and do not correspond to `canvas.moveto()`.

Here's the used image:

[image]

What is happening here?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow people to test your code and help diagnose the problem more quickly

Comment: How do you create the item `image`? Also you used different item ID `image` and `item`, are they refer to same canvas item?

Comment: @acw1668 I uploaded the full demonstration. And yes, item and image refers to the same canvas image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That behavior is documented and you observing the functionality as it is intended.
`canvas.coords(item)` will return where the item currently is.
`canvas.moveto(item, *coord_list)` will place the item so that the upper left corner is below and next to the coordinates in `*coord_list`.

Compare the documentation of [`coords`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M42) with  [`moveto`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/canvas.htm#M60).

> If no coordinates are specified, this command returns a list whose
> elements are the coordinates of the item named by tagOrId.

and

> Move the items given by tagOrId in the canvas coordinate space so that
> the first coordinate pair (the upper-left corner of the [bounding box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62712481/13629335))
> of the first item (the lowest in the display list) with tag tagOrId is
> located at position (xPos,yPos)

This small snippet code demonstrate your experience:

```
import tkinter as tk

def test(event):
    cnvs.moveto(rect, *cnvs.coords(rect)[0:-2])

root = tk.Tk()
cnvs = tk.Canvas(root, highlightthickness=0)
cnvs.pack()
rect = cnvs.create_rectangle(0,0,50,50, fill='red')
print(cnvs.coords(rect))
root.bind('<1>', test)
root.mainloop()
```

while changing the function test to the following will solve the issue:

```
def test(event):
    delta = int(float(cnvs.itemcget(rect, 'width'))/2)
    coords = [coordinate-delta for coordinate in cnvs.coords(rect)[0:-2]]
    cnvs.moveto(rect, *coords)
```

**However, you would need to tweak it for different item-types with other coordinate properties as well. The usual way to update coordinates with tk and tkinter is to use `canvas.coords(item, *new_coords)` anyway.**

Comment: Hi. Your solution only works for rectangle of width 1. If you change it to, for example, 4, like `cnvs.create_rectangle(…, width=4)`, it will not work properly

Comment: @DanyaK fair point, will update this answer.